# How to hide menu button of pgs4a(pygame subset for android)?

Tags: android, python, pygame, htc-android

I developed an app from android using pgs4a. On my galaxy s4 it fits on the screen and works perfectly. On an HTC One (M7) however a menu button appears on the bottom of the screen causing the app to not fit on the screen properly. Anyone who has used pgs4a knows that when the app doesn’t fit properly on the screen it creates very ugly sidebars. If nobody knows how to get rid of the menu bar it would be helpful if somebody at least knew the exact height of the menu button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your targetSdkVersion to 14

reference: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html